# Custom Select Query - Selecting the Year?

Tags: posts, customization, query

I have a query were I'm grabbing all post types of "news" in 2010, but it doesn't select the posts from that year. What am I doing wrong?

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'news'
    AND year($wpdb->posts.post_date) = 2010,
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";
```

Taking this line out does fetch the news posts, but really I want them from a particular year.

```
AND year($wpdb->posts.post_date) = 2010,
```

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This question appears to be a **SQL syntax** question, rather than a **WordPress** question.

Comment: the appropriate answer to this involves WordPress knowledge, aka use a WP_Query object

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the direct SQL query, there's no point and it's bad practice.

Instead use WP_Query:

```
$year = date('Y');
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'year' => $year,
        'post_type' => 'news'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AND year($wpdb->posts.post_date)='2010',
```

instead of:

```
AND year($wpdb->posts.post_date) = 2010,
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately this didn't work. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Does `$wpdb->posts.post_date` need to be passed through `strtotime()` first, perchance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
AND $wpdb->posts.post_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
```